# How to Custom policy AD B2C TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

How to Custom policy AD B2C TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml

I would like to customize ADB2C policy of TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml which I prefer the response to be as below

```
{
     "ver": "1.0",
      "iss": "test",
      "sub": "test",
      "aud": "test",
      "exp": test,
      "acr": "test",
      "nonce": "defaultNonce",
      "iat": 1685010692,
      "auth_time": 1685010692,
      test: {
       "lname": "q",
       "fname": "q",
       },
      "idp": "test",
      "tid": "test"
    }
```

How should I customize TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Bit confused by this.

You wouldn't use the Extensions file to do this.

You would use the RelyingParty file e.g. B2C_1A_signup_signin where the outputs are the attributes (claims) you want returned in the JWT.

**Update**

This is not possible. However, you can pass [stringified JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61555758/aad-b2c-output-a-nested-json-object-in-a-jwt-for-hasura).

Comment: if i fix OutputClaims in file B2C_1A_signup_signin. how to fix code for result like this 
{
 test: {
       "lname": "q",
       "fname": "q",
       },
}